# input text classification using nltk

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, classification, nltk

I have data set of 5500 questions -[link1](https://github.com/karimkhanp/nltk_data/blob/master/corpora/qc/train.txt) and Keywords of 6 categories - [link2](https://github.com/evandrix/nltk_data/tree/master/corpora/qc)

I want to perform two actions

1. Classifying the category of input question based on given data set in both links
2. Classifying the category of Named entities in input sentence for above link2 data set

Initially I started with gender classification just to know how classification can be done, and it works pretty nice.

```
>>> def gender_features(word):
...     return {'last_letter': word[-1]}
>>> gender_features('Shrek')
{'last_letter': 'k'}

>>> from nltk.corpus import names
>>> labeled_names = ([(name, 'male') for name in names.words('male.txt')] +
... [(name, 'female') for name in names.words('female.txt')])
>>> import random
>>> random.shuffle(labeled_names)

>>> featuresets = [(gender_features(n), gender) for (n, gender) in labeled_names]
>>> train_set, test_set = featuresets[500:], featuresets[:500]
>>> classifier = nltk.NaiveBayesClassifier.train(train_set)
>>> classifier.classify(gender_features('Neo'))
'male'
>>> classifier.classify(gender_features('Trinity'))
'female'
```

In similar manner I tried to classify input word from any of the category listed in `link2`. But I could not identify what  `feature extraction function` should I use here.

Any help or suggestion for 1,2 action would be much appreciable.

Comment: [Link 2: Keywords of 6 categories](https://github.com/evandrix/nltk_data/tree/master/corpora/qc) in your question is broke. Can you provide the information if you still need ideas around features?